# Changepoint detection when there is no supposed change

Tags: r

## Problem

I have accelerator pedal position and brake pedal force variables for multiple drivers. **I want to know when they start to push either pedal**.  In most cases, the drivers either push the gas pedal or the brake pedal only. For example:

[image]

The small plot on the left shows the complete data and the plot on the right shows the data after the `Observe` line. I am only interested in the data after the `Observe` line. Please note that the gas pedal position (green points) ranges from 0 -1 and brake pedal force ranges from 0 - 82 kg. The plots show the scaled vectors.

Here, even the largest variation in the brake pedal force is not supposed to be considered as a changepoint, because driver only pushed the gas pedal. This is more clear in the left plot.

## Desired outcomes

I need the index of the point where the change starts (gas or brake pedal being pushed). However, if the change is very small, as in the case of brake pedal force in the plots, then no changepoint should be detected.

## What I have tried

I used the `changepoint` package as follows:

### Data (see the sample data `veh` at the end)

```
veh <- perc_CF_lead_veh_only %>% filter(file.ID == "truck_neg_100_2_Ahmed.hdf5",
                                        frames > frame_obs) %>% 
  select(file.ID, frames, frame_obs, ED_gas_pedal_pos, ED_brake_pedal_force_kg)
```

### Changepoint detection

```
library(changepoint)

start_change_speed <- veh %>% 
  group_by(file.ID) %>% 
  filter(frames > frame_obs) %>% 
  summarize(brake_start_index = cpts(cpt.meanvar(ED_brake_pedal_force_kg)),
            gas_start_index = cpts(cpt.meanvar(ED_gas_pedal_pos))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

### Result:

```
> start_change_speed
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  file.ID                    brake_start_index gas_start_index
  <chr>                                  <dbl>           <dbl>
1 truck_neg_100_2_Ahmed.hdf5                53             342

plot(cpt.meanvar(veh$ED_brake_pedal_force_kg))
```

[image]

> I don't want to consider this detected changepoint (in the brake pedal force)as a *change* because it is not an actual change but probably happened due to the noise/error in the measurement.

```
plot(cpt.meanvar(veh$ED_gas_pedal_pos))
```

[image]

### Example data

```
dput(veh %>% select(-file.ID))
structure(list(frames = c(107189, 107190, 107191, 107192, 107193, 
107194, 107195, 107196, 107197, 107198, 107199, 107200, 107201, 
107202, 107203, 107204, 107205, 107206, 107207, 107208, 107209, 
107210, 107211, 107212, 107213, 107214, 107215, 107216, 107217, 
107218, 107219, 107220, 107221, 107222, 107223, 107224, 107225, 
107226, 107227, 107228, 107229, 107230, 107231, 107232, 107233, 
107234, 107235, 107236, 107237, 107238, 107239, 107240, 107241, 
107242, 107243, 107244, 107245, 107246, 107247, 107248, 107249, 
107250, 107251, 107252, 107253, 107254, 107255, 107256, 107257, 
107258, 107259, 107260, 107261, 107262, 107263, 107264, 107265, 
107266, 107267, 107268, 107269, 107270, 107271, 107272, 107273, 
107274, 107275, 107276, 107277, 107278, 107279, 107280, 107281, 
107282, 107283, 107284, 107285, 107286, 107287, 107288, 107289, 
107290, 107291, 107292, 107293, 107294, 107295, 107296, 107297, 
107298, 107299, 107300, 107301, 107302, 107303, 107304, 107305, 
107306, 107307, 107308, 107309, 107310, 107311, 107312, 107313, 
107314, 107315, 107316, 107317, 107318, 107319, 107320, 107321, 
107322, 107323, 107324, 107325, 107326, 107327, 107328, 107329, 
107330, 107331, 107332, 107333, 107334, 107335, 107336, 107337, 
107338, 107339, 107340, 107341, 107342, 107343, 107344, 107345, 
107346, 107347, 107348, 107349, 107350, 107351, 107352, 107353, 
107354, 107355, 107356, 107357, 107358, 107359, 107360, 107361, 
107362, 107363, 107364, 107365, 107366, 107367, 107368, 107369, 
107370, 107371, 107372, 107373, 107374, 107375, 107376, 107377, 
107378, 107379, 107380, 107381, 107382, 107383, 107384, 107385, 
107386, 107387, 107388, 107389, 107390, 107391, 107392, 107393, 
107394, 107395, 107396, 107397, 107398, 107399, 107400, 107401, 
107402, 107403, 107404, 107405, 107406, 107407, 107408, 107409, 
107410, 107411, 107412, 107413, 107414, 107415, 107416, 107417, 
107418, 107419, 107420, 107421, 107422, 107423, 107424, 107425, 
107426, 107427, 107428, 107429, 107430, 107431, 107432, 107433, 
107434, 107435, 107436, 107437, 107438, 107439, 107440, 107441, 
107442, 107443, 107444, 107445, 107446, 107447, 107448, 107449, 
107450, 107451, 107452, 107453, 107454, 107455, 107456, 107457, 
107458, 107459, 107460, 107461, 107462, 107463, 107464, 107465, 
107466, 107467, 107468, 107469, 107470, 107471, 107472, 107473, 
107474, 107475, 107476, 107477, 107478, 107479, 107480, 107481, 
107482, 107483, 107484, 107485, 107486, 107487, 107488, 107489, 
107490, 107491, 107492, 107493, 107494, 107495, 107496, 107497, 
107498, 107499, 107500, 107501, 107502, 107503, 107504, 107505, 
107506, 107507, 107508, 107509, 107510, 107511, 107512, 107513, 
107514, 107515, 107516, 107517, 107518, 107519, 107520, 107521, 
107522, 107523, 107524, 107525, 107526, 107527, 107528, 107529, 
107530, 107531, 107532, 107533, 107534, 107535, 107536, 107537, 
107538, 107539, 107540, 107541, 107542, 107543, 107544, 107545, 
107546, 107547, 107548, 107549, 107550, 107551, 107552, 107553, 
107554, 107555, 107556, 107557, 107558, 107559, 107560, 107561, 
107562, 107563, 107564, 107565, 107566, 107567, 107568, 107569, 
107570, 107571, 107572, 107573, 107574, 107575, 107576, 107577, 
107578, 107579, 107580, 107581, 107582, 107583, 107584, 107585, 
107586, 107587, 107588, 107589, 107590, 107591, 107592, 107593, 
107594, 107595, 107596, 107597, 107598, 107599, 107600, 107601, 
107602, 107603, 107604, 107605, 107606, 107607, 107608, 107609, 
107610, 107611, 107612, 107613, 107614, 107615, 107616, 107617, 
107618, 107619, 107620, 107621, 107622, 107623, 107624, 107625, 
107626, 107627, 107628, 107629, 107630, 107631, 107632, 107633, 
107634, 107635, 107636, 107637, 107638, 107639, 107640, 107641, 
107642, 107643, 107644, 107645, 107646, 107647, 107648, 107649, 
107650, 107651, 107652, 107653, 107654, 107655, 107656, 107657, 
107658, 107659, 107660, 107661, 107662, 107663, 107664, 107665, 
107666, 107667, 107668, 107669, 107670, 107671, 107672, 107673, 
107674, 107675, 107676, 107677, 107678, 107679, 107680, 107681, 
107682, 107683, 107684, 107685), frame_obs = c(107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 
107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188, 107188), ED_gas_pedal_pos = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0292913392186165, 0.0412598438560963, 0.0563779510557652, 
0.07433070987463, 0.0913385823369026, 0.110866144299507, 0.130393698811531, 
0.151181101799011, 0.171338587999344, 0.193070858716965, 0.214488193392754, 
0.236535429954529, 0.260157465934753, 0.2796850502491, 0.301102370023727, 
0.32125985622406, 0.342677175998688, 0.366614162921906, 0.393070876598358, 
0.418582677841187, 0.445354342460632, 0.467401564121246, 0.488818883895874, 
0.504881918430328, 0.519999980926514, 0.533858239650726, 0.546771645545959, 
0.554960608482361, 0.562834620475769, 0.570393681526184, 0.576692938804626, 
0.584881901741028, 0.592440962791443, 0.602834641933441, 0.612913370132446, 
0.621732294559479, 0.630551159381866, 0.638425171375275, 0.645669281482697, 
0.649763762950897, 0.653858244419098, 0.658267736434937, 0.66519683599472, 
0.672125995159149, 0.677480340003967, 0.682204723358154, 0.686299204826355, 
0.690078735351562, 0.694173216819763, 0.698582649230957, 0.701732277870178, 
0.706141710281372, 0.70992124080658, 0.713700771331787, 0.715590536594391, 
0.718740165233612, 0.721574783325195, 0.723149597644806, 0.725984275341034, 
0.730078756809235, 0.733543336391449, 0.739842534065247, 0.742992103099823, 
0.746771633625031, 0.750236213207245, 0.752755880355835, 0.754960656166077, 
0.757480323314667, 0.759370088577271, 0.761259853839874, 0.762519657611847, 
0.765354335308075, 0.766614198684692, 0.769763767719269, 0.773228347301483, 
0.778267741203308, 0.783307075500488, 0.788661420345306, 0.794330716133118, 
0.797795295715332, 0.802204728126526, 0.805039346218109, 0.807874023914337, 
0.808818876743317, 0.809133887290955, 0.809133887290955, 0.810078740119934, 
0.811338603496552, 0.811653554439545, 0.813228368759155, 0.815748035907745, 
0.817952752113342, 0.822047233581543, 0.825511813163757, 0.828976392745972, 
0.832755923271179, 0.836535453796387, 0.840314984321594, 0.841574788093567, 
0.844724416732788, 0.845984280109406, 0.846929132938385, 0.847874045372009, 
0.849448800086975, 0.850078761577606, 0.850078761577606, 0.850078761577606, 
0.849763751029968, 0.848818898200989, 0.850393712520599, 0.852913379669189, 
0.855118095874786, 0.85700786113739, 0.857637822628021, 0.859842538833618, 
0.861417293548584, 0.863622069358826, 0.864881873130798, 0.866456687450409, 
0.867716550827026, 0.869921267032623, 0.87055116891861, 0.871496081352234, 
0.87212598323822, 0.872755885124207, 0.871811032295227, 0.874330699443817, 
0.874015748500824, 0.874015748500824, 0.874330699443817, 0.873700797557831, 
0.87464565038681, 0.873700797557831, 0.874330699443817, 0.874330699443817, 
0.873385846614838, 0.875275611877441, 0.874330699443817, 0.874330699443817, 
0.874960601329803, 0.874330699443817, 0.874330699443817, 0.87464565038681, 
0.874960601329803, 0.873700797557831, 0.874960601329803, 0.873385846614838, 
0.874015748500824, 0.873700797557831, 0.874330699443817, 0.874015748500824, 
0.87464565038681, 0.87464565038681, 0.873385846614838, 0.873070895671844
), ED_brake_pedal_force_kg = c(0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 
0.298896709084511, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 
0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 
0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 
0.321210756897926, 0.49900084733963, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 
0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 
0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 
0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 
0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 
0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 
0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 
0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 
0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 
0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0, 0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 
0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 
0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 
0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 
0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 
0.332367780804634, 0.310053732991219, 0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 
0.265425637364388, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 
0.343524804711342, 0.310053732991219, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 
0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 
0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 
0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.365838879346848, 0.343524804711342, 
0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 
0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 
0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 
0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 
0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 
0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 
0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 
0.321210756897926, 0.298896709084511, 0.310053732991219, 0.321210756897926, 
0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.365838879346848, 
0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.310053732991219, 
0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.310053732991219, 0.343524804711342, 
0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 
0.365838879346848, 0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 
0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 
0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 
0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 
0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 
0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 
0.343524804711342, 0.365838879346848, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 
0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 
0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 
0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 
0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 
0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 0.310053732991219, 
0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 
0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 
0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 
0.332367780804634, 0.310053732991219, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 
0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 
0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 
0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 
0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.310053732991219, 
0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 
0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 
0.310053732991219, 0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 
0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 
0.520140463113785, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 
0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 
0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 
0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 
0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 
0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 
0.310053732991219, 0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 
0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 
0.343524804711342, 0.310053732991219, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 
0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 
0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 
0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 
0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 
0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 
0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 
0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 
0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 
0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 
0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 
0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 0.310053732991219, 0.343524804711342, 
0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 
0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 
0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 0.310053732991219, 0.321210756897926, 
0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 
0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 
0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 
0.298896709084511, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 
0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 
0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 
0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.365838879346848, 
0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 
0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 
0.310053732991219, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 
0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 
0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 0.310053732991219, 0.332367780804634, 
0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 
0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 
0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 
0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 
0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.310053732991219, 
0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 
0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 
0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 
0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 
0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 
0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 
0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 
0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 
0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 0.287739685177803, 0.332367780804634, 
0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 
0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 
0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 
0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 0.310053732991219, 0.321210756897926, 
0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 
0.343524804711342, 0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 
0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.310053732991219, 
0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 
0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 
0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 
0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 0.321210756897926, 
0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 0.310053732991219, 0.321210756897926, 
0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342, 0.332367780804634, 0.332367780804634, 
0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 
0.321210756897926, 0.332367780804634, 0.321210756897926, 0.343524804711342, 
0.332367780804634, 0.343524804711342)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -497L), .Names = c("frames", 
"frame_obs", "ED_gas_pedal_pos", "ED_brake_pedal_force_kg"))
```